# Decision making with if statement consists of multiple variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have four variables. I want to check if all of the four variables equal to 0, then some statements execute. 
I tried some solutions but none of them worked.
How could I solve this problem?
Here is my code snippet:

```
var coun1 = 0;
var coun2 = 0;
var coun3 = 0;
var coun4 = 0;

if(all of the variables equal to 0) {
   //some code here
}
```

Comment: `if(coun1+coun2+coun3+coun4 !== 0)` , if none can be negative.

Comment: Or `if( coun1 === 0 && coun2 === 0 && coun3 === 0 && coun4 === 0 )`

Comment: What kind of a solution do you expect? A built-in function to check 4 variables to be 0?

Comment: @dandavis But that doesn't account for negative numbers

Comment: You mean a simple logic like: if (coun1 == 0 && coun2 == 0 && coun3 == 0 ...) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all variables are in an array, this is easier. Otherwise, you need to perform some type of operation on each variable individually - whether that be adding them together, or checking each one. But, if they are rearranged as an array, simply use the [`array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method:

```js
const counArray = [
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0
]

if(counArray.every(coun => coun === 0)) {
   //some code here
}
```

But also, if that's not an option, you can use one of these from the comments here:

- Example 1: `if (coun1+coun2+coun3+coun4 !== 0) ...`
- Example 2: `if (coun1 === 0 && coun2 === 0 && coun3 === 0 && coun4 === 0) ...`